# Having trouble defining a piecewise function in r?

Tags: r

How would you define this piecewise function in r?

f(x) =

1, 0 ≤x ≤1

0, otherwise

Comment: `function(x) as.integer(x >= 0 & x <= 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing the function as shown below. It ensures that the function can be evaluated at some points and vectors. Additionally, this form lets to plot the piecewise function correctly due to the vectorization without using other functions (Vectorize).

```
f <- function(x) {
  (0 <= x & x <= 1) * 1 + 0
}

f(x=0.5)       # 1
f(x=2)         # 0
f(x=c(0.5, 2)) # 1 and 0

curve(expr=f, from=-1, to=1)
```

In general, if we had this piecewise function
[image]

We can represent it in R as follows:

```
fdp <- function(x) {
 (x >= 2 & x <= 3) * (0.5*x-1) + (x > 3 & x <= 6) * (1-x/6) + 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
f <- function(x) if (0 <= x & x <= 1) 1 else 0

f(.5)  # 1
f(2)   # 0
```